# Sqlalchemy : association table for many-to-many relationship between template_id and department. How can I delete a relationship?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

```
Department = models.department.Department

association_table = Table('template_department', models.base.Base.instance().get_base().metadata,
                      Column('template_id', Integer, ForeignKey('templates.id')),
                      Column('department_id', Integer, ForeignKey('departments.id')))


class Template(models.base.Base.instance().get_base()):

    __tablename__ = 'templates'


    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tid = Column(String(7), unique=True)
    ....

    departments = relationship('Department', secondary=association_table)
```

I'm trying to delete the relation between many template_id and department but I can't really come up with a query that does it. Any way to do this using Sqlalchemy?

Comment: Just to make sure: by "I'm trying to delete the relation between many template_id and department" you mean "remove rows from the association table" for a given set of `(template_id, department_id)` tuples or some such, or any relations between any of the given ids? The question is a bit unclear as it is.

Comment: Remove rows from association table

Comment: Do you have a set of template_id, department_id pairs to remove, or something else?

Comment: Yes. I have to remove pairs.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can use [row constructors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-subqueries.html) and the [IN-operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to remove rows from *association_table* that match the pairs. For example if you had list of template_id, department_id pairs such as:

```
to_remove = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), ...]
```

then you could

```
from sqlalchemy import tuple_

stmt = association_table.delete().\
    where(tuple_(association_table.c.template_id,
                 association_table.c.department_id).in_(to_remove))

session.execute(stmt)
...
```

Note that this bypasses normal ORM book keeping, so instances that exist in your session may now contain stale data. If you intend to commit right away and reload data if needed, this is not a problem.

Comment: can you tell me, how the query will be, if i want to remove rows specific to a department, for example, department_id = 2, and i want to find all rows related to department_id = 2, and delete the rows

Comment: That's even simpler, just `where(association_table.c.department_id == 2)`. The same caveats about possibly stale data apply, so you either should commit right away after the bulk delete, or you have to refresh your session instances. The documentation on [`Query.delete()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) covers the possible issues that might arise (they apply even though the example is using Core).

Comment: line 202, in _delete
    query = session.query(association_table).delete().\
  File "/Users/royce/phoenix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3073, in delete
    delete_op.exec_()
  File "/Users/royce/phoenix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1126, in exec_
    self._do_pre_synchronize()
  File "/Users/royce/phoenix/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1180, in _do_pre_synchronize
    target_cls = query._mapper_zero().class_
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'class_'

Comment: `association_table` is not a mapped class, but a Core `Table`, so don't use the Query API with it in that fashion. See the example in the answer for how to build the DELETE statement using Core.

Comment: Why cant i use "where" or "filter". Gives and attribute error. "Int" object has no attribute "where".

Comment: `where()` is for Core selectables. `filter()` is part of the Query API (ORM stuff). `"Int" object has no attribute "where"` means that you're doing something really odd. Check your code for typos or other errors. Do you possibly have something like `association_table.c.department_id.where(...)`?