# Delete multiple rows with sqlalchemy given two columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have one table, it's a join table and basically is just two columns: `(id_a, id_b)`.

I have a list of tuples:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Which are essentially rows from said table.

How can I use sqlalchemy to delete these all at once in a batch operation? There is no other primary key column in the table, just *id_a* and *id_b*.

```
SomeSession.execute(user_flag.delete(...))
```

Comment: What database are you using? Are you using the ORM? If so, can you not delete the associations using the relationships?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258545/sqlalchemy-association-table-for-many-to-many-relationship-between-template-id

Answer (score 0):

What you're aiming to do is essentially the same as a delete statement in SQL just using sqlalchemy. They constructed the module to emulate SQL commands and to do the batch delete all you'd have to do is:

```
SomeSession.execute(user_flag.delete())
```

where user_flag is the table you are looking to empty.

ref http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#deletes
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html?highlight=delete#insert-updates-deletes